# How to convert a multidimentional array to json that is readable by ajax

Tags: json, ajax

I have this multidimentional array in ajax.php

```
$data = array( array( "Red", "Blue", "Green"), array("Kate", "Tender", "Vortex"), array("9", "2", "11"));
echo json_encode($data);
```

And I'm trying to access it by $.get request as such:

```
$("#my_bt").click(function(){
    $.get('ajax.php', function(data){
        alert(data[0][0]);
});
});
```

In this instance I am trying to alert "Red" but the output is "[" which is the first letter of the returned data.

What json format should be used to be able to access all the data within the arrays? Or to convert the existing ones?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `dataType` property as `"json"` to get the content returned in *JSON* format:

```
$.get('ajax.php', function(data){
   alert(data);
}, "json");
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: thanks, so if you don't use $.ajax you have to specify the datatype?

Comment: @OliverFox, yes. And `$.ajax` method is more powerful and advanced for performing HTTP (Ajax) requests